# Automatically create date sequences with different starting dates in R

Tags: r, date

I can create the desired date sequences using the following code:

```
DateTwoWeeks1 <- seq(as.Date("2010/8/6"), as.Date("2011/8/5"), by = "2 weeks")
DateTwoWeeks2 <- seq(as.Date("2010/8/7"), as.Date("2011/8/5"), by = "2 weeks")
DateTwoWeeks3 <- seq(as.Date("2010/8/8"), as.Date("2011/8/5"), by = "2 weeks")
```

However, I would like to automate the creation of the date sequences for 14 different starting dates. I would like to have one time series starting on the 6th of August 2010, the next time series starting on the 7th, so on until the 19th of August 2010.

How can I automate this? I tried it using the "paste" function but I couldn't get the following code to work:

```
for (i in 6:19){
TimeTwoWeeks[i] <- seq(as.Date(paste("2010/8/", i)), as.Date("2011/8/5"), by = "2 weeks")
}
```

Any direct help or linkage to other websites/posts is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
TimeTwoWeeks <- lapply(as.Date("2010/8/6") + 0:13, 
                       function(X) seq(X, as.Date("2011/8/5"), by = "2 weeks"))
```

Comment: You can simplify the `lapply` call as `lapply(as.Date('2010-08-06') + 0:13, seq, as.Date('2011/08/05'), '2 weeks')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a list of the time series you could adjust as follows:

```
TimeTwoWeeks <- list()

for (i in 6:19){
TimeTwoWeeks[[i-5]] <- seq(as.Date(paste("2010/8/", i)), as.Date("2011/8/5"), by = "2 weeks")
}
```

Comment: You probably want to index the list with `i-5` to avoid 5 NULL list elements at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me out. All your suggestions were really useful